# jgit need 2 arguments error message

Tags: java, eclipse, jgit

I am trying a simple java class to test the functionality of jGit (see below).

```
import org.eclipse.jgit.lib.Repository;
import org.eclipse.jgit.storage.file.FileRepositoryBuilder;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;


public class CreateRepository {
   public static void main( String[] args ){
       Repository myrepo = createRepository("/mypath");
   }
public static Repository createRepository(String repoPath) {

        FileRepositoryBuilder builder = new FileRepositoryBuilder();
        Repository repo = null;
        try {
            repo = builder.setGitDir(new File(repoPath))
              .readEnvironment() // scan environment GIT_* variables
              .findGitDir() // scan up the file system tree
              .build();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    return repo;
}
}
```

When i run this on Eclipse Indigo with latest jgit jar in my build path i get the error message "Need 2 arguments" - nothing else, no exceptions! :S

Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The only part of JGit which displays that error message is in the [main() function of `MyersDiff`](https://github.com/eclipse/jgit/blob/master/org.eclipse.jgit/src/org/eclipse/jgit/diff/MyersDiff.java#L527-L533).

```
/** 
 * @param args two filenames specifying the contents to be diffed
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
  if (args.length != 2) {
    System.err.println(JGitText.get().need2Arguments);
    System.exit(1);
  }
  // ...
}
```

So check your classpath and make sure your project (and your `main()`) are *before* the jgit.jar, and that you don't somehow calls the wrong `main()`.

Answer (score 1):

First look into package org.eclipse.jgit.api.
The easiest start is from class Git:

```
// clone a repository
Git git = Git.cloneRepository().setURI("git://yourserver/repo.git").call();

// init a fresh new repository in the current directory
Git git = Git.init().call();

// open a repository on your disk
Git git = Git.open(new File("/path/of/repo");
```

Then explore the commands available on the git object you get
from these starting points.